# Missing file doc comment?

Tags: drupal, phpcodesniffer

I used drupal [coder](https://www.drupal.org/project/coder) module to check my code and always get missing file doc as an error.
I used the following file doc comment but still showing error. Can you please guide me what am i doing wrong.
**Edit**:

```
 <?php

/**
 * @file
 * Description
 */


/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 *
 * Description
 *
 * @return array An array of menu items
 */
function hook_menu() {
 //My code
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding php version to your file it will look like /* PHP 5 */

Comment: Can you give me example? I checked drupal standard module https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/7commenting  and there is also an issue of missing file comment. May be this issue is of codesniffer?

Comment: i jsut read a blog http://blog.rajatpandit.com/2009/10/01/php-code-sniffer-and-common-errors/

Comment: Added PHP version 5 but still got the issue

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typical first 15 lines of a file:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Description of what this module (or file) is doing.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 */
function yourmodule_help($path, $arg) {
  // or any other hook...
}
```

Don't forget to also comment the first function of you file with /** or else coder will believe that your @file comment is your first function's comment.

Comment: I have no permission to do that. Please check my file code below:
`<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Description of file
 */


/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 *
 * Description of function
 *
 * @return array An array of menu items
 */
function lr_social_login_menu() {
  //My code
}`